# Question about prepositions/conjunctions (from, to...)

Tags: prepositions, british-english

Can you please tell which (if any) of the following is correct?

> 1. Where are you coming from?/From where are you coming?
> 2. Who will you give it to?/To whom will you give it?
> 3. What for?/For what?

Comment: 'Correct' as regarded by a prescriptivist grammar teacher, or 'correct' in the sense that Professor Pullum would let you in for a glass of sherry if he heard you say it?

Comment: The grammar wiz :)

Comment: Which of these are conjunctions in your sentences?

Comment: I am really new to English and sorry if they aren't :$

Comment: They're all fine, perfectly grammatical. The first two pairs vary in formality; the second ones, with the fronted prepositions (they're not conjunctions), are rather snooty. The first ones in 1 and 2 are normal questions. The third pair is rather drastically shortened, with the meaning depending on the context. These two differ. They're both fixed phrases, but not the same fixed phrase. _What for?_, all by itself, simply means _Why?_. _For what?_, on the other hand, either is asking for a repeat, or is expressing disbelief, or asking for a specific reason. Depending on intonation and stress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why didn't you post your response as an answer below? :P

Answer (score 2):

*Where are you coming from?/From where are you coming?*

- less formal (speech) / more formal (speech or writing)

*Who will you give it to?/To whom will you give it?*

- less formal (speech) / more formal (speech or writing), but I'd argue that even the informal should use the grammatically correct *whom*.

*What for?/For what?*

- The meanings of these sentences are somewhat different.  *What for?* means *Why?*, while *For what?* means *What is its purpose?*, or is used as an expression of disbelief, as previously mentioned.